# How to get Parameter from Ext.Ajax.request in java controller

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am having one problem in retrieving the parameter which i am passing using Ext.Ajax.request to my JAVA controller class.

I am sending request to my controller using below code

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
             url : 'projecttask/GetprojectTasks.action',
             method: 'POST',
             jsonData: {
                sampledata: record.data
            },
            type: 'json',
            scope: this, // add the scope as the controller
             callback : function(options, success, response) {
                console.log('RESPONSE FROM SERVER :'+response);
             }
           });
```

my java controller method to receive the request is

```
@RequestMapping(value="/projecttask/GetprojectTasks.action")
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, ? extends Object> getprojectTasks(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,@RequestBody Project project) throws Exception {
        try {
            System.out.println("PROJECT ::"+project);
            System.out.println("RPOJECT DATA ::"+request.getParameter("sampledata"));
            Object data = request.getParameter("sampledata");
            Project prj = (Project) data;
            System.out.println("CREATE TASK DATA IS ::"+prj.getProjectid());            
            return null;            
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return getModelMapError("Error trying to create contact");
        }
    }
```

but it gives me error mentioned below

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Unrecognized field "sampledata" (Class com.kintu.projectmgt.model.Project), not marked as ignorable
```

so what i am doing wrong which not allowed my function to get sampledata passed as parameters. How can i get my Parameters passed value any idea ?

My firebug shows that sampledata contains all values. Please help me to find the problem and solve it as soon as possible.

**I am using Ext JS 4.0.2a and JAVA as my serverside technology.**

Comment: sorry but i solved my error by removing the jsonData and type from my Ajax Request. Instead i had just added  **params: {'id':record.get('id')}** and on server side i get the values with **request.getParameter("id")**

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
String postParamsJSON = request.getReader().readLine();
```

to get the POST data.